# Готов ли ASP.NET Core MVC для продакшена?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

Здравствуйте, вопрос к тем, кто уже работал с платформой ASP.NET Core MVC. Ранее работал с ASP.NET MVC, однако сейчас приобрел по новой платформе литературу и планирую после прочтения заняться разработкой на ней. Безусловно будущего никто не знает, но я думаю общую картину уже можно обрисовать. На сколько сильно фремверк может претерпеть изменений, что бы после нового релиза не пришлось переучиваться и переписывать проект? На сколько сыра платформа? Как много подводных камней при работе с ней, если можно - детальней? И вообще готова ли она к продакшену, например для разработки корпоративного портала?

Comment: По поводу подводных камней: сам хотел попробовать её в своём тестовом проекте, но наткнулся на серьёзное препятствие: .NET Core не предназначена для работы в оффлайновом окружении. Т.е. если на ваших рабочих машинах нет доступа в интернет и нет никакого прокси, то готовьтесь к танцам с бубном, чтобы заставить её нормально работать. Соответственно, и на билд-сервере будут те же проблемы.

Comment: а подскажите какую литературу приобрели?

Comment: Адам Фримен ASP.NET Core. Читал от этого же автора издание для ASP.NET MVC 4 - довольно хорошо изложено было.

Comment: Фримена читать стоит конечно же, но к сожалению к ASP.NET Core 1.1 не применимо. Там "тулинг" поменяли =(

Comment: @klutch1991 никаких танцев. Достаточно своего репозитория nuget.

Comment: @PavelMayorov а у нас есть вопрос о том, как этот репозиторий правильно поднять и настроить? Если нет — не хотите ли написать его?

Comment: @NickVolynkin к сожалению, я никогда не занимался этим, хотя с локальным репозиторием работал

Comment: Готов, уже вторая версия же.

Comment: Вот доклад, человек делится личным опытом https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ngcigr_8oxw

Comment: @Bulson не желаете оформить ответом? Только не просто ссылку, чтобы в случае удаления видео остался ответ

Comment: @VadimProkopchuk а что нужно написать в ответе кроме ссылки? Если что у меня нет опыта использования сабжа в продакшене.

Comment: @Bulson, Да хотя бы тезисно написать, что автор хотел донести

Comment: @VadimProkopchuk для этого мне нужно время:) Время для того, чтобы пересмотреть доклад и законспектировать его.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я думаю, что ответ - Да. ASP.Core MVC готов для использования
в продакшене.

В качестве доказательства можно привести доклад
**Дениса Иванова** из компании **2GIS** на конференции **DotNext 2017**
(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ngcigr_8oxw)

**ASP.NET Core приложения под Linux в продакшене**

В качестве конспекта привожу выдержки из слайдов доклада.

*Сервис видеорекламы*

Требования:

- 99.99% доступности по миру
- время отклика 200ms

*Почему Linux*:

- Существующая on-premise платформа
- -GitLab CI
- -CI starting kit на основе make
- -Docker hub & docker images
- Компоненты на любом технологическом стеке
- Kubernetes

*Поддержка принципа "12-ти факторного приложения"*

- 1) Одно приложение - один репозиторий
- 2) Зависимости - вместе с приложением
- 3) Конфигурация через окружение
- 4) Используемые сервисы как ресурсы
- 5) Фазы билда, создания образов и исполнения разделены
- 6) Сервисы - отдельные stateless процессы
- 7) Port binding
- 8) Масштабирование через процессы
- 9) Быстрая остановка и запуск процессов
- 10) Среды максимально похожи
- 11) Логирование в stdout
- 12) Административные процессы

*.NET Core. Self-contained deployment*

- Полный контроль зависимостей
- Явное указание платформы при билде  (win10-x64 / ubuntu.14.04-x64 / osx.10.12-x64)
- Только необходимый фреймворк

*Вместо заключения*

- Не бойтесь использовать .NET Core в продакшене
- Не бойтесь использовать Linux и .NET Core
- Docker и Kubernetes сильно упрощают жизнь
- Пишите эффективный код правильно